# JavaScript output by PHP doesn't run in Safari

Tags: javascript, php

So, I can't release any of the code, but I am having this bug where a user clicks "accept" for the T&C sets cookie parameter to 1 and then runs this javascript code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.close();";
echo "window.opener.location.href = '" .  BASE_URL . "';";
echo "</script>";
```

Closes the T&C window (doesn't happen), and opens a link to BASE_URL.  Now, this code works fine in Chrome/Firefox, however in safari, nothing happens the T&C window stays open.  Any ideas? (Yes, I have enabled js in safari)

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's console for errors?

Comment: JS can only .close() a window if it was used to open that window in the first place, usually...

Comment: No errors, and @MarcB it works fine in ff/chrome

Comment: What calls this code?

Comment: @JayBlanchard a button press (accept on T&C)

Comment: You can't usually call `close()` if you didn't call `open()` yourself. Make sure to open the T&C using the `open()` function.

Comment: Thanks @Reda I wil look into that ..